# Fibered product of Hopf Fibrations

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration

I am wondering: what is the vector bundle associated to the Hopf-fibration $S^{3}\to S^{2}$?

What is the fibered product of two Hopf-fibrations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$Modulo orientation, the *complex* line bundle coming from the Hopf map $\pi:S^{3} \to S^{2}$  is the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\Proj^{1}}(-1)$, whose total space is the blow-up of $\Cpx^{2}$ at the origin. (The same real $2$-plane bundle with the opposite orientation is the hyperplane bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\Proj^{1}}(1)$, whose total space is the complement of a point in $\Cpx\Proj^{2}$.)

The fibre product of the Hopf map with itself (i.e., the pullback of the Hopf bundle by the Hopf map) is the torus bundle over $S^{2}$ whose fibre over a point $p$ is $\pi^{-1}(p) \times \pi^{-1}(p)$. The total space is a circle bundle over $S^{3}$ in two ways, by projecting away the respective factors.

---

Identify the circle $S^{1}$ with the multiplicative group of unit complex numbers. If $\pi:P \to M$ is a principal $S^{1}$-bundle over a smooth manifold $M$ and $\rho$ is an effective linear representation of $S^{1}$ on $\Cpx$ (i.e., $\rho(e^{it})$ is multiplication by $e^{it}$, or by $e^{-it}$), then there is a complex line bundle
$$
E = P \times_{S^{1}} \Cpx \to M,
$$
in which the action of $S^{1}$ on $P$ is the principal action, and the action on $\Cpx$ is via $\rho$.

The usual norm on $\Cpx$ induces an Hermitian metric in $E$, for which the total space of $P$ is the unit circle bundle.

The $2$-sphere may be identified with $\Cpx\Proj^{1}$, the space of complex lines through the origin in $\Cpx^{2}$, and the $3$-sphere may be identified with the set of unit vectors in $\Cpx^{2}$, whereupon the Hopf bundle $P = S^{3} \to S^{2}$ is identified with the projection sending a unit vector $x$ to the (complex) line through $x$, viewed as an element of $S^{2}$.

The action $S^{1} \times S^{3} \to S^{3}$ defined by $(e^{it}, x) \mapsto e^{it}x$ endows $S^{3}$ with the structure of a principal circle bundle over $S^{2}$. If $\rho$ is an effective representation of the circle on $\Cpx$, the associated complex line bundle is obtained from the restriction of the circle action
$$
S^{1} \times (\Cpx^{2} \times \Cpx) \to \Cpx^{2} \times \Cpx,\qquad
(e^{it}, x, v) \mapsto (e^{it} x, e^{\pm it}v).
\tag{1}
$$

If $S^{1}$ acts by conjugate multiplication on $\Cpx$, the associated complex line bundle is obtained from the restriction of the circle action
$$
S^{1} \times (\Cpx^{2} \times \Cpx) \to \Cpx^{2} \times \Cpx,\qquad
(e^{it}, x, v) \mapsto (e^{it} x, e^{-it}v).
$$
The product $(x, v) \mapsto vx$ is invariant under the action, so we may identify the second factor $\Cpx$ with the line through $x$, subject to the understanding that "each line has its own origin/zero vector". The latter is precisely the total space of the blow-up of $\Cpx^{2}$ at the origin. The induced complex line bundle is $\mathcal{O}_{\Proj^{1}}(-1)$.

The action of $S^{1}$ by ordinary multiplication also has a familiar interpretation. Equation (1) becomes the action of $S^{1}$ on $\Cpx^{3}$ by scalar multiplication, whose quotient is $\Cpx\Proj^{2}$. Since $x$ is point of $S^{3}$, i.e., a unit vector in $\Cpx^{2}$, the point $[0:0:1]$ is not in the image; that is, the total space of this line bundle is the complement of a point in $\Cpx\Proj^{2}$. The projective line $S^{2}$ sits "at infinity", and the bundle projection is radial projection from the origin. In algebraic geometry, this complex (in fact, holomorphic) line bundle is the "hyperplane bundle" $\mathcal{O}_{\Proj^{1}}(1)$.

The underlying (unoriented) real $2$-plane bundles are equivalent under fibrewise conjugation.

Comment: thanks. Do you know some reference where to read the details?

Comment: @Bilateral: You're welcome. I'll add some details to the post, since there's an orientation issue I glossed over. As for (additional) references, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up) seems to have a reasonably detailed explanation of blowing up a point in $\mathbf{C}^{2}$. Not positive where I picked up this material; probably Griffiths and Harris in large part.

Comment: @Bilateral: There's a fairly detailed sketch included; it seemed best not to hand-wave too much, since getting the signs consistent is a bit fussy, and different sources may or may not use the same conventions. (I didn't go so far as to write out transition functions for the line bundles, instead favoring geometric assertions about each bundle's identity and leaving algebraic justification as a "straightforward exercise" if you feel inclined.)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the update!